# insert a character after every nth character using groovy

Tags: groovy

I am using groovy and ended up with some long strings. I need to insert 
 after say every 50th character. How do i do that?

could not find any option other than traversing the string via index and put something.

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively do a split using regular expression and then concatenation using `join` method.

Example:

```
​def input = 'abCDSasdDSdsds'
def splitted = input.split(/(?<=\G\w{5})/)
// or you can write . instead of \w

assert 'abCDS:asdDS:dsds' == splitted.join(':')
```

​

Comment: Or `input.toList().collate(5)*.join().join(':')`

Comment: I've just found it when i was searching for how to split string into parts of a specific length.  
You can read more about \G [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) - it is a special anchor which matches the end of the previous match.  
You can read more about ?<= [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) - it is a positive lookbehind, it steps backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there

Comment: So, actually, `/(?<=\G\w{5})/` matches "blank space" after 5 symbols which were after the end of the previous match. You can check it here: https://regex101.com/r/hB6hX4/1 (it's supplied with some explanation)